# Une nuance entre « ressentir », « éprouver » et « se sentir »

Tags: sens

> J’ai **ressenti** un soulagement incroyable.
>
> J’ai **éprouvé** un soulagement incroyable.
>
> Je **me** suis **sentie** incroyablement soulagée.

Je m’interroge sur la différence entre les trois, que ce soit celle de sens ou de registre, si légère soit-elle. Ou est-ce qu’ils sont interchangeables l'un avec l'autre ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Niveau registre, "*se sentir*" est courant, les deux autres légèrement plus soutenus, surtout **éprouver**.

"*Éprouver*" est toujours pour une émotion ou un sentiment, "*ressentir*" peut aussi s'appliquer à quelque chose d’extérieur. Pour le reste, la différence est assez minime. Je dirais que *ressentir* s'applique aussi plus facilement à des petits sentiments, *éprouver* est un mot assez fort.

"*Se sentir*", peut s'appliquer pour des émotions, mais c'est surtout le mot de choix pour tout ce qui état malade ou similaire. Il est suivi par un adjectif ou un participe présent, donc la fonction est différente dans la plupart des cas : "*je me sens balloné, faible, fiévreux*", on ne peut pas utiliser les autres mots pour ce genre de choses. On ne peut pas non plus dire des choses comme "*je me suis sentie apeurée*", etc.

Mais les trois mots restent très proches.

Comment: On ne pourrait donc pas dire  "**éprouver** un tout petit peu d'enthousiasme" au lieu de "**ressentir** un tout petit peu d'enthousiasme" ? Merci. :)

Comment: J'irai dans le sens de la réponse en disant que "se sentir"a un sens assez léger : il s'agit ici de sensations potentiellement purement physiques
Ressentir est forcément une sensation intérieure à mon avis, pas forcément un sentiment mais déjà quelque chose de plus profond (quand on ressent le froid, ce n'est pas juste le froid sur la peau, qui serait "sentir" mais le froid qui donne l'impression d'avoir froid intérieurement)
Eprouver est pour moi quelque chose de plus profond encore "Eprouver une difficulté" par exemple est possible, mais pas vraiment la sentir ou la ressentir